# How can I apply cut() separately to each line of a data frame using purrr::map()?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to apply a certain row-wise operation to a data frame.

The goal is to create a new data frame - or a list that I'd later convert to a data frame - with labels instead of numbers. To get what I wanted, I applied the function `cut()` to the numbered data frame using `purrr::map()`.

I **expected** a list with two objects, each containing 15 elements. **What I got** was a list with 15 objects, each with 2 elements. It seems map was applied column-wise, and not row-wise.

The code below demonstrates what is happening.

**How can I force the operation to work row-wise?**

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)

a_matrix = matrix(data = sample(100,30),nrow = 2)
a_matrix
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#> [1,]   72   29   47    9   44   62   73   60   56    85    21    78   100
#> [2,]   16   74   90   34   99   50    7   53   28    38    12    96    40
#>      [,14] [,15]
#> [1,]    51    22
#> [2,]    58    52

a_df = data.frame(a_matrix)
a_df
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
#> 1 72 29 47  9 44 62 73 60 56  85  21  78 100  51  22
#> 2 16 74 90 34 99 50  7 53 28  38  12  96  40  58  52

cut_modif = function(x) {
  cut(x,
      breaks = quantile(x),
      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
      include.lowest = T,
      right = T
  )
}

map(a_df,cut_modif)
#> $X1
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X2
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X3
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X4
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X5
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X6
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X7
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X8
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X9
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X10
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X11
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X12
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X13
#> [1] D A
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X14
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
#> 
#> $X15
#> [1] A D
#> Levels: A B C D
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: For rowwise operations see `purrr::pmap()`.

Comment: I tried ```purrr::pmap()```but it was to no avail either. @aosmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In base R**

You can use `apply` function from base r. This function apply a function to the rows or cols of an array.

```
apply(a_df, 1, cut_modif)
```

**Using `purrr::map`**

When you pass a dataframe as argument to `purrr::map` to iterate over, the iteration is done by column, not by row. So, to do what you want I only see two options:

1. Reshape your dataframe to a tidy format, where values are in rows and variables in columns

```
a_df = data.frame(t(a_matrix))

map(
  a_df,
  cut_modif
  )
```

2. Slighly modify your `cut_modf` function to recibe a row index as argument

```
a_df = data.frame(a_matrix)

cut_modif = function(.df, row) {
  x <- .df[row, ] %>% as.numeric()

  cut(x,
      breaks = quantile(x),
      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
      include.lowest = T,
      right = T
  )
}

map(
  1:nrow(a_df),
  ~cut_modif(.df = a_df, row = .x)
  )
```

Comment: Hey, Johan. Thanks for the feedback. I'm aware I can use ```apply```but at this point I'm interested in learning why it didn't work with ```map```. Also, in this case, I'll also not get exactly what I wanted. Once more, I'd get only 2 columns when I want the original 15 columns back. PS.: I know I can transpose the answer.

Comment: Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: I'll admit that I was expecting - and hoping - for something simpler. But your solution works and it's not that more complicated. Thanks for your contribution.